# What is the size of this hypothesis space?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics

Let Σ be a finite alphabet and let X = Σ^ be a sample space of all strings of length  over Σ. Let H be a hypothesis space over X, where H = {ℎw: Σ^ → {0,1},  ∈ Σ∗, 0 <||≤, .. ℎw() = 1       }.

What is |H| in terms of |Σ| and m?
From my calculations I think it might be [image](2^(combinations of |Σ| taken m))? But I am not quite sure.

Comment: This looks like homework. If so, i needs the `self-study` tag and also needs to be expressed in terms of what difficulty is being encountered in finding a solution.

Comment: One often sees powers, like $|\Sigma|^m,$ *defined* as the cardinality of the set of maps $\{1,2,\ldots,m\}\to\Sigma$ (which is the set of "strings of length $m$ over $\Sigma$"). Two straightforward applications of this definition will give you the answer.